# Monitors connected to a Dock are not found

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, hp, displayport

I have a [Dell WD15](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/dell-dock-wd15/overview) dock and an HP Envy 13 ([13-ad012na](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c05596484)) running KDE Neon 20.04, and I cant get DisplayPort monitors to work through it. I've found the following error in `dgmesg` when I connect a monitor to the dock:

```
[drm:drm_dp_send_link_address [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* Sending linkaddress failed with -5
```

And I see the following in `xrandr`:

```
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

My wife has the same laptop running Windows 10 and it works fine, so the hardware side of things is fine, and my work laptop (a Dell) runs Ubuntu and also works fine, so the software is fine (if configured correctly). I've also tried using a different USB-C hub with an HDMI post and it works fine with the Envy 13.

I'm at a loss as to why my Envy 13 doesn't connect. It has support for DisplayPort over USB-C alt mode, which the WD15 dock uses, so I'm not sure if I have a messed up config somewhere or something else I don't understand. The Envy 13 has an nvidia MX130, which needs optimus to access, the rest of the time I use the Intel 620 graphics chip.

I have tried installing the DisplayLink drivers after another suggestion elsewhere, but that seemed to make no difference.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Sorry, updated my question.

Comment: What is Linux KDE 20.04?

Comment: It's me being stupid, I meant KDE Neon 20.04